# Why is string.length()=0 after processing string using string[i]?

Tags: c++, string

I made a program in C++ to take a sentence as input and wanted display the sentence after omitting the spaces , however I'm getting weird results ...
s2 is the string containing the sentence after omitting spaces.
I can access the string s2 as s2[i] , but I'm getting no output when I try cout<< s2; and value of s2.length() gets printed as 0 ??

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s1,s2;
    int i,j,l1,l2;
    getline(cin,s1);
    l1=s1.length();
    j=0;
    for(i=0;i<l1;i++)
    {
        if(s1[i]!=' ')
        {
            s2[j]=s1[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    cout<<s2.length();
    cout<<s2<<endl;
}
```

Expected : s2.length() shouldn't be 0 and cout<< s2; should work.

Comment: Good read: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at

Comment: Please don't tag with unrelated tags. This is, clearly, not C.

Comment: Use `push_back` to add characters

Comment: And you need  `#include <string>`

Comment: Try and get out of the habit of `using namespace std`. That prefix is there for a reason: To protect you from naming collisions and to make it clear where those functions, data structures and other things come from.

Comment: `string s1,s2;` now you have a string `s2` with length 0, and after that you never change its length...

Comment: `s2[j]` is undefined behavior, with any value of `j`, if `s2` is empty.

Comment: `operator[]` does not grow the string if you go beyond the bounds. You must set the size yourself in some way before accessing those elements.

Comment: [Here: read a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), it will teach you how `std::string` works and other important topics.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. The question clearly explains the problem and presents an reproducible example. IMHO, it is a reasonable question even if one has read a c++ book.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> s2[j]=s1[i];
> ```

`s2` is initially empty. Accessing `s2[j]` is out of bounds and undefined behavior.

Change it to `s2+=s1[i]` and all is good.

---

**Update** FYI, in mordern C++ you don't usually need to deal with lengths because you should prefer using standard library algorithms:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s1,s2;
    getline(std::cin,s1);
    std::copy_if(s1.begin(), s1.end(), std::back_inserter(s2), [](char ch){
        return ch!=' ';
    });
    std::cout<<s2.length();
    std::cout<<s2<<'\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The length of a default-constructed string is 0.

`s2[j]` accesses the character at the index `j`. If that character doesn't exist, then the behaviour of the program is undefined.

When the length of the string is 0, for any `j` greater than 0, `s2[j]` has undefined behaviour, because that character doesn't exist. `s2[0]` is well defined and refers to the null terminator.

You may have intended to add characters to the string. You can add characters to a string for example using the `push_back` member function or `+=` operator.

Comment: "s2[0] is well defined and refers to the null terminator." really? has this always been the case?

Comment: i got used to the fact that I will never stop learning c++, but its a bit intimidating that strings can still be a big surprise to me ;)

Comment: the behaviour was present already before c++11, it only changed to be more consistent between the two overloads (details [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at))

Comment: @user463035818 oh, so it is. Only the non-const one was UB. I must have mixed up with the other guarantee that was added in C++11, which is that the buffer is null terminated even without `c_str`.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that either.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [] to increase the s2 string size. If you use resize to grow it beforehand, it should work:

```
        s2.resize(j+1);
        s2[j]=s1[i];
        j++;
```

push_back() of a character on a std::string would do the same. However, I offer you this answer as it keeps the character assignment you already had. Philosophy of minimal answer/change :-).

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that is, in principal, what `push_back` does.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s1,s2;
    int i,l1;
    getline(cin,s1);
    l1=s1.length();
    for(i=0;i<l1;i++)
    {
        if(s1[i]!=' ')
        {
            s2.push_back(s1[i]); //CHANGE MADE HERE
        }
    }
    cout<<s2.length();
    cout<<s2<<endl;
}
```

As @iBug mentioned you can also use push_back as shown above